# Java <-> C Bridge

Tags: java, c, linux, sockets, rpc

I'm working on a application which has Java web interface hosted on Glassfish server and C kernel which is implemented as Linux daemon.

My biggest problem right now is how to make Remote Procedure Calls. I need to call functions and methods in both directions. These are the possible solutions that I can think of:

1. Use Java Native Interface and network sockets to implement RPC.
2. D-Bus - as far as I know DBus can be used for RPC between Java and C.

I want to use the most basic way without using external libraries or frameworks.
Is it possible directly to call functions/methods between Java and C using only sockets? The OS that I use is Centos.

Is there more elegant way to connect the two languages?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without external libraries, only sockets remain. But I would classify DBus as an external library, wouldn't you?

If the C program can use sockets, there is no need for Java Native Interface. The Java code can [open sockets from Java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html), calling the sockets the C code listens to.

If you allow DBus, maybe you should consider the plethora of networking and RPC protocols which have libraries for both C and Java. (Again, no need to use JNI.)

Going the DBus way, look at the [Java documentation](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-java/) and the [tutorial](http://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-tutorial.html).

Comment: Would you give some more information how this can be implemented?

Comment: @user1103606 This is a fairly advanced topic, so it hard to give a simple answer to this. Do you know how to write TCP socket connections and call methods (e.g. using reflection ?)

Comment: I have a knowledge how to write C Network server and client program. Would you explain how to call C methods from java using only sockets? What is reflection?

Comment: Reflection is basically that you can ask server about capabilities and methods it exports. If you can write server and client code in C, it's very much the same in Java.

Comment: @user1103606, since you know how to create C socket servers, I added a link to how to open sockets from Java clients, Oracles Lesson 1.

Comment: How I can call C/Java functions and methods using the sockets. Would you explain me deeply how RPC between different programming languages work?

Comment: @user1103606, there is no direct and simple way to just call functions between the programs. With third party libraries you can do it, but they all involving encapsulating functions in protocols. Look for Hessian protocol, XML-RPC, ZeroC ICE, CORBA and so on.